# Android Studio Error: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: android, android-studio, error-handling

I'm currently trying to build a dummy app using Android Studio. I can't even get a new project built because of the Run Build error "Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" (among other errors, including gradle). Important to note that this is a work Macbook, so I've already hit a few speed bumps regarding proxies.

I understand that many people have had this issue when dealing with different APIs/libraries. My issue is that I receive this error within 5 seconds of trying to build a brand new project. Any insight is much appreciated!

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your hard disk has space before trying to run a build on Android Studio